# Check "any" param in JMockit NonStrictExpectations

Tags: java, jmockit

I have this `NonStrictExpectations`:

```
new NonStrictExpectations(){
  {
    mDogDao.saveAllDog((Collection<Dog>) any);
    // do some validation on **any**
    times = 1;
  }
};
```

How can I do some assertions on the `any` parameter?
I know that is definitely possible... but I do not know what I have to look for.

Thanks for your support.

Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Verifications` instead of `Expectations`:

```
new Verifications() {{
    Collection<Dog> dogCollection;

    mDogDao.saveAllDog(dogCollection = withCapture());

    assertEquals(5, dogCollection.size());
}};
```

Have a look at [the withCapture() documentation](http://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/BehaviorBasedTesting.html#withCapture) for more information.